# How Do I list all user pools using AWS Lambda in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

How do I get List of User Pools from Cognito? Also After getting userpool how do I get list of users in particular userpool?

I am using Nodejs Lambda function to fetch the data from the congnito.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`CognitoIdentityServiceProvider`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html) service, you can call the [`listUserPools()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#listUserPools-property) method to list the user pools associated with your AWS account and get the **UserPoolId** that you can pass to the [`listUsers()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#listUsers-property) method to list the users in that Amazon Cognito user pool.

Comment: I wish to get the user pools and not identity pools

Comment: @DarshPatel: Sorry, i misread your question. Please see my updated answer.